# UK tourist visa refused 3 times. Need to get there for flight home

Tags: air-travel, visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, australian-citizens

Around 3 years ago I applied for a temporary working visa for the UK, but it got rejected because I lied to the police once and had some old [DUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driving_under_the_influence) charges. So I never went to the UK.

I recently arrived in Gatwick on a flight from Amsterdam while on my journey backpacking around Europe. I though surely for those offences a tourist visa would be OK, but no. After keeping me all night, they decided to send me back to Amsterdam. They told me the main reason was that I didn't have any documents with me concerning my transit out of the UK (all of it is on the internet).

When in Amsterdam I collected the massive pile of flight information which I had already booked weeks earlier – my flight home to Australia is from London.

Then I tried to catch the Eurostar from Belgium with the documents they'd asked for. The way I was treated was so disgusting that I still can't believe it. I was asked if I was a "Shanty" (whatever that is). When I told an officer that I'd planned to stay in Brixton to see my friend, he asked me, "Is he black?" When I said, "No – *she's* not," he said, "There's a lot of black people there." This may give you an idea into the kind of "people" I was dealing with.

After hours of intense questioning where he'd try to catch me out on any tiny little thing I said, and actively try to trick me, and say, "This stamp was wrong," or, "That stamp doesn't exist" and me having to grab the passport and show it to him, they said no, because now they thought I'd work illegally. They knew I wasn't going to, and they knew I knew. It was just about them winning and me doing as I was told. Even if they were wrong.

He told me there was nothing stopping me going to Dublin. So, with only a few days left on my Schengen visa, I did. And they, like every other country I've been to in my 4 years of backpacking, let me in. And today I flew to Glasgow, and soon I will take the train to London.

My problem is, I have a flight booked from London to Iceland, then a return flight to London, where I have 5 days before my flight back to Aus., and they will again probably stop me. My question is this: if I enter the UK from the EU and am rejected again, what will they do with me if my visa is not valid anymore for the country I arrived from? If they'll send me home, that's fine, and to be honest, I'd love to see the UK pay for that after all the money and stress they've caused me. My other question is – if I book a connecting flight to Dublin – will I still have to pass immigration? Or can I stay in the security area?

Comment: Not sure about all your questions, in principle if you cannot be sent back to the place you came from, you should be deported to your home country (I know for a fact that's how it works other European countries but I don't know precisely about the UK). OTOH, you experienced yourself how arbitrary all this is, some countries have been known not to care too much and then the border guards in Iceland (which is not in the EU btw) would have to decide what to do with you.

Comment: But if you have a connecting flight and you are already on your way out, they are unlikely to prevent you from taking that flight, it would just cost them a lot of effort and money for no reason. If they really want to prevent you from entering the UK or make your life miserable, I imagine that you could be detained until the departure of that flight (be warned, I know people working in detention centres for illegal immigrant and it's not pretty…).

Comment: Thats a hard one- go to iceland and risk detention or stay in UK untill departing home..... I think Iceland are in the Schengen Zone,that suprised me too. Thanks again!

Comment: Iceland is a member of the Schengen Area, but not an EU member. When were you born (this is actually relevant for your rights in the UK as a Commonwealth citizen)? Who payed for your flight back to Amsterdam after you were refused entry in Gatwick? How did you get through immigration in Glasgow when arriving from Dublin? More details on your criminal record (when were you sentenced to what) may also be relevant.

Comment: @Annoyed:"But if you have a connecting flight and you are already on your way out, they are unlikely to prevent you[...]". I would definitely *NOT* count on common sense of the border patrol. It is not their money they would have to invest to make life miserable for other people and they can always hide behind bureaucracy.

Comment: If "they" send you home, it'll be "you" that pays for the flight, not them...

Comment: No it won't, they paid for my flight back to Amsterdam. They'll have to torture me before I give up my bank account details- the commonwealth means absolutely nothing. I was born in Australia- funnily enough there is no passport control between Republic of Ireland and the UK, it was just like a domestic flight.

Comment: I am considering buying the return flight from Iceland to Dublin, then entering again to take my flight back to Aus. But flights are in excess of $600 with many long stopovers in Europe, and my EU visa will be expired by that stage. By the way the immigration officers sounded, the charges aren't really relevant anymore- it's just about.... well your guess is as good as mine. 
Thanks again everyone

Comment: @Doc In practice, recovering money internationally is always difficult and most people who are deported don't have much left at the end of the procedure anyway, I am not sure many countries bother.

Comment: What's relevant at this point is that you have been refused entry, and that alone is always going to make further entry difficult.  Your correct course of action is to obtain a visa for entry to the UK, and that is what you should have done after your initial refusal.  For many countries this is mandatory after having been refused entry, and whilst I don't think that's the case for the UK, it would still be the recommended path to go.

Comment: @Doc: Having an issued tourist visa for the UK is actually still not a guarantee that you are granted entry. Even with a visa, the entry clearance officer may reject you at the UK border if he assumes that the conditions for issuing a visa is no longer met. Just as when refusing entry for persons not usually required to have a visa, this decision is at the discretion of the entry clearance officer and may not be appealed on site.

Comment: @Ben: Are you really sure that the UKBA paid for your return flight to Amsterdam without issuing you a re-entry ban? That sounds quite unlikely. Are you sure that the ticket was actually paid for and that the airline won't charge you (later) for the flight?

Comment: I have been told that for deportations between friendly countries they can actually get your embassy to pay for the ticket and then your country will want you to bloody well pay that back. This might make a good separate question to find out if it's true. I've also heard of them getting a family member to pay. Not sure if that's true either.

Comment: By the way I have had similar problems with US immigration many years ago, and I've heard it's much worse now.  I had a very nice travel agent who refunded my nonrefundable ticket so I could fly home not through the US. You could try that. I've also heard similar stories at Australian immigration. I think our three countries are perhaps the worst three for this. I'm an Aussie too.

Comment: Embassies never, ever pay for anything.  In extreme cases they might loan you some money, but they'll most certainly want it back.  See: http://www.dfat.gov.au/publications/consular-operations-handbook/part4.html#Chapter_17:_Travellers_emergency_loans_issued_by_Australian_honorary_consuls_and_Canadian_posts

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo: Ireland is *not* a member of Schengen, and the UK has made it clear that if Ireland joins, they will pull the plug on the Common Travel Area (=easy UK-Ireland travel).

Comment: @Doc I thought that the visa-after-refusal route was specifically a US thing, I have never heard of it elsewhere. In the Schengen area, I think you can only try your luck at the border again or possibly try to appeal any entry in the SIS somehow. I would think that obtaining a visa is neither helpful nor possible if your citizenship does not require one in the first place. But I might be wrong about all that.

Comment: @jpatokal: If you notice what I said, I was in fact describing a type of loan.

Comment: If you get deported from one country it may prejudice your chances of obtaining a visa in other countries. You will also have blown any chance of returning to the UK.

Comment: @Annoyed: I always believed the opposite, that for most countries have been denied entry or deported or "asked to leave" would always make subsequent visa applications or entry attempts more difficult. This is why it's a question on many visa applications and landing forms.

Comment: @Annoyed: Your citzenship is just one of the factors which determine whether or not you need a visa. In my case as an Aussie I would not need a visa for USA, but the fact that I have some ancient drama with US immigration trumps that and means I do need a visa. This is explicitly stated about the place. Same goes for places where you might not need a visa for a short stay or tourism visit, but might need one for a long stay or to visit on business or to work, etc.

Comment: @JoshB: "Any chance"? Are you sure? Including a chance twenty years in the future? I think you need to back up or soften that claim.

Comment: @JoshB: First of all, Ben has not been deported from the UK, but has been refused entry. Those are two quite different issues. Even if he had been deported, UK allows deported (in the meaning of forcefully removed from the country) persons to return after 10 years. Other breaches of immigration regulations may lead to shorter entry bans or not necessarily being an issue at all when reentering UK, e.g. overstaying a visa for less than 90 days and then leaving UK voluntarily at your own expense.

Comment: Yes, I know he hasn't been deported yet. However Ben appears to take the chance of being deported quite lightly. Thank you for clarifying the rules regarding deportation and the UK. This is why I put my comment in a comment.

Comment: @hippietrail Well, I knew about this US practice but I don't think it's the way it works for the Schengen area for example (I am talking about short stays meeting all the usual conditions obviously). If you would not need a visa for a particular trip but there is somehow an entry about you in the SIS, you're mostly screwed. Obviously having been deported might make entry more difficult but the only way around that is to formally complain in front of the authorities of the relevant country. I believe applying for a visa is neither formally required nor possible.

Comment: Also, an entry in the SIS would also be a reason to deny a visa, the visa application process is not intended to be a way to have your case reexamined or grant exceptions to any bans or unfavourable records.

Comment: I think you may mean a [DUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUI) charge. A [DIY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIY) charge is something completely different.

Comment: I thought Australian Nationals don't need any visa to enter in the United Kingdom.

Comment: theres so many conections between england and ireland immigations services...them exchange data informations....i get deported from ireland last year..and that time the immigation officer said to me ``i could travel to any part of EU ``but i coudnt travel to ireland anymore... so i got the ticket from Brazil to Paris last month and i got in Paris whithout trouble...but i get caught on Paris train station tryng to get a train to london...so i presume that them have a lot data exchange information on them computer centre...because before u get in to the train in Paris( Paris -London) you need to

Comment: How did you pass through immigration in Dublim? was it easy?@Ben

Comment: So you have been refused entry twice, then illegally entered the UK and you wonder if you will be allowed in next time!?

Answer (score 34):

Here's what ended up happening-

I flew into Glasgow from Dublin with no problems, once there I caught a bus down to London. Also with no issues. I spent a while there, saw the sights and caught up with old friends. Just like I stated I would.

Then after much contemplation decided to take the leap and continue with my return trip to Iceland, consequences be dammed!

As some people on here have stated, leaving the UK was no problem, I got a puzzled look when the immigration person saw my rejection stamps but other than that it was all ok.

Went to Iceland, had the most amazing leg of any journey in that wonderful place… then it was time to try return to London. I had booked a transfer from London to Dublin for the return, hoping I could evade the immigration “system” but there are certain connecting airlines that have to clear immigration before continuing to there connecting flight. There is actually a massive sign listing who needs to clear immigration and who doesn't. Of course all the Irish connections did, so they got me again.

Even though I had done everything I had told them I was here to do i.e. tourist things, I'm sure they weren't too happy with the fact that i had disobeyed them. I won't go into all the details but basically they put me in a detention centre for a week untill my flight home was due (the one I had booked months earlier).

It was quite an experience, I got the rare opportunity to meet real asylum seekers and hear about the true ordeals people face and the heartless system of our well-off nations. I shared rooms with people being sent home to certain death, it was a really eye opening experience. And I'm glad it happened the way it did.

I hope this helped anyone in a similar situation.

Comment: Oh and thank you to everyone for your useful advice!

Comment: +1 for coming back to tell us what happened, although I do hope you realize you're likely banned from the UK for life now...

Comment: Its too late for this now, but I would have suggested extending your stay in Iceland and simply transiting through the same airport which would avoid immigration.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, it's interesting to hear your experience and a shame you weren't able to use the advice provided through this forum to avoid this exact outcome.

Comment: @jpatokal Are you sure these things are for life? I would suspect some limit of 10 years

Comment: I'm not sure what the formal limits are, or how his final attempted entry was recorded, but three refused entries and one possible deportation is *really* not going to look good the next time he applies for a visa...

Comment: Something similar happened to me, except the detention centre was in Bangkok! Not a happy place ...

Comment: So we have a 'heartless system' in which people who knowingly, wilfully and repeatedly break the rules are punished for it. Whatever next.

Comment: I suspect that after that experience with the UK he might be left with such an impression of our attitudes and humanity that it even outweighs the oudoubted beauty of our many splendid culinary delights, joyous dormitory suburbs and eternal drizzle.

Comment: @DJClayworth well, according to what I managed to understand, it's the immigration officer who started making troubles out of nowhere, when OP's initial intention was simply turism… it escalated, sure, but you can't blame _him_ if _they_ started it for no reason.

Comment: @o0' Owing to a previous visa refusal, his decision to just show up was extremely risky. If someone has been refused before, people on this site advise getting a visa rather than counting on the usual admittance at the border even for Australians, Americans, etc.

Answer (score 32):

I'm sorry, but you've screwed yourself well and proper here.  Not only have you been refused entry *three times in a row*, which means that any future visa applications will be treated with extreme prejudice, but *you've now illegally entered the United Kingdom as well*.

To expand on that last bit, just because there are no border *controls* between Ireland and the UK doesn't mean that your Irish visa gives you any right to be the UK.  Per [section 2.6](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/sitecontent/documents/policyandlaw/enforcement/oemsectiona/chapter2?view=Binary), you should have applied for a visa, or at the very least presented yourself to an immigration officer at the border:

> ...the following do require leave to enter the United Kingdom on
>   arrival from the Irish Republic:
>
> **Persons who have at any time been
>   refused leave to enter the United Kingdom and have not since been
>   given leave to enter or remain in the United Kingdom.**
>
> Persons from the above categories who enter the United Kingdom from the Irish Republic without leave do so in breach of Article 3 of the Immigration (Control
>   of Entry through Republic of Ireland) Order 1972 (as amended) and are illegal entrants.

However, not all hope is necessarily lost.

First, the United Kingdom is one of a few countries without exit immigration, so now that you're in the country, illegally or not, there's nothing stopping you from leaving to Australia... or Iceland.

Second, major airports like Heathrow allow [visa-free transit](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/transitthroughtheuk/visa-transit-airside/).  Since both your flights from Iceland and to Australia are international flights, you can complete the transfer without ever passing through immigration, if and only if all of the following conditions are met:

1. You're arriving to and departing from the same airport
2. You can check your bags through to Australia (unlikely), or you have no checked baggage, so you don't have to pass through Immigration to fetch and recheck it

I can't find anything that says you can't spend 5 days airside, but obviously you'll want to change one of your flights to minimize this if at all possible.

But if you can't meet those conditions, then I'd advise you to forget Iceland, lay low in London, and head home to Australia.  Immigration detention is not fun, and it's entirely possible that they wouldn't even let you on the plane in Iceland, in which case you'd be even more screwed.

Comment: Who would prevent boarding the flight in Iceland? Surely, the airline has no access to previous UK entry decision. Wouldn't he still look like a regular Australian citizen who does not need visa?

Comment: Airlines supply API data to the UK, which I presume would flag undesirables in return before they get on the plane.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-Borders

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't know about that program. Still, it seems that, if anything is done at all, it's being used to stop people at the arrival gate: http://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2013/oct/09/e-borders-scheme-failing-to-stop-terror-suspects

Comment: Heathrow may allow visa-free transit, but I have been stopped by UK Immigration while checking in. So there's a small chance that "Annoyed" will have more interaction with Immigration.

Comment: @jpatokal: +1, thanks for the clarification. I erronously assumed that exit immigration must be passed and if it is true what you said I can only say to Ben that he was indeed very lucky to be in a country which does not have exit immigration....whew.

Comment: One of the conditions of visa-free transfer is that you can spend only 24 hours in the UK.

Comment: I've transited Reykjavik airport numerous times and if you are flying to the US/UK your passport is checked at a border control manned by Icelandic officials before boarding.  If you are flying in the Shengen there is a different part of the airport and you don't pass through that control

Answer (score 7):

The first thing a traveller in trouble should do is contacting their embassy/consulate.
As you are in Glasgow now, the next Consulate is in Edinburgh:

Mitchell House
5 Mitchell Street
Edinburgh EH6 7BD
Tel: +44 131 538 0582

Unfortunately it is an Honorary Consul (meaning that he isn't really paid for his job and has very limited rights, so do not expect much). Perhaps it is better that you call directly the Embassy in London:

Strand
London WC2B 4LA.
Tel: 020 7379 4334

Explain your situation (and DO NOT LIE !!!!). Hopefully they can sort out the trouble you are in.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'm pretty sure I could leave the UK with not many issues, but I really don't wan't to loose the iceland trip, which I've already paid for. But I will visit the Embassy in London and explain my situation. Thanks

Comment: It is unlikely that the Australian embassy in London will be able to have any influence on any decisions made by the UK Border Agency.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: Sure, but they can get that piece of information and tell Ben that decision. If it comes to the worst, they should be able to get him a flight back from Glasgow to home even if he loses his money for the London ticket. Pushing his luck and driving with a train to the UK and hoping for the best after repeatedly rebuffed does not sound like a good idea. Do you have a better one ?

Comment: Glasgow is still in the UK, at least until the Scottish independence referendum in 2014. My best bet would be to stay in the UK and leave with the already booked flight to Australia. Ben already told why he was refused entry. Why do you think that the Australian embassy will get a different explanation from the UK Border Agency?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: Sorry for mixing up UK und England. The problem I see is that a border control will happen in London when Ben tries to border the plane. Scotland and Wales are relatively independent in their decisions, you cannot extrapolate that he won't get in trouble because he entered already the UK.

Comment: And it is not that I expect the embassy as a silver bullet, but as a necessary backup if something happens. Better the embassy know that you are trying to leave and do not intend to make trouble *before* something happens. You can be detained without charge for extended periods without anyone knowing your whereabouts in the UK.

Comment: I honestly think you are mixing a lot of concepts here. Even if Scotland and Wales are relatively independent, they do of course practise the same immigration policy as England, all being part of the UK. From what Ben writes in his question, one cannot assume that he currently is illegaly in UK and there is no reason to expect problems when leaving London on a flight to Australia. He has been refused entry several times, but is as an Australian citizen not required to obtain a visa in advance and entered the UK regularly on his flight to Glasgow.

Comment: @Ben: I would contact the airline or agent you bought your ticket with, tell them the story, and see if they will change it. A Ryanair might not help out but places with humanity might. Worked for me in a similar situation in the past.

Comment: @Thorsten S.: As there is no exit immigration in the UK, he will not be 'caught' when departing.

Comment: If I do go to the Embassy, I'm just a little concerned that they may be obliged to report my situation to the authorities? I have no idea how they work. 

Unfortunately my Iceland flight is from Gatwick, the flight home is from Heathrow; I think if I went back to Dublin and flew into Gatwick in transit to Iceland, then flew back through Gatwick in transit to Dublin..... wait there for a few days then fly Dub - Heathrow (in transit) - Perth, that may work? It's alot of hassle though and thats 3 more flights for something that I don't know will even work. 
In London now- heading to the Embassy

Comment: That would *probably* work, but it's going to be a hassle alright, and you're taking a bit of a risk anytime you fly to the UK.  The Australian embassy is not going to report anything to the UK, but they can't fix this for you, all they can do is offer you advice.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: in practice though he's not just any old Australian, he's an Australian who has previously been refused a work visa and then refused entry again as a tourist. Furthermore, he *didn't* enter the UK regularly at Glasgow, it's that presenting yourself at immigration between Ireland and the UK is on the basis of the "honour system". You might as well say that if you arrive from (say) India and walk through the "nothing to declare" channel with a backpack full of cigarettes then you've imported them regularly into the UK. A court would not agree ;-)