# Deportation from Ireland

Tags: visas, ireland, deportation

I'm from Congo but I study in Tbilisi Georgia. I was in Ireland on a tourist visit but I was refused "permission to land" because they believed my  "intentions for visiting Ireland were not genuine". The immigration officer said I had lied to him about my intentions for visiting Ireland; that some of the places which I intended to visit were either not tourist attractions or they weren't functioning anymore. So I was deported back to Tbilisi Georgia. But now I intend to reapply for the Irish visa again, this time for academic purpose. Will my visa application be granted or will it be refused because of the deportation?

Comment: There is a difference between being deported and not being let in. Sometimes what gets written up is just that you voluntarily withdraw your application to enter. This is different from being refused entry, or being deported. It's important for you to know what happened because applications typically ask if you've been deported or refused entry.

Answer (score 19):

It depends; there is no definite "yes" or "no" answer to this question. It might even depend only on the mood of the immigration officer who processes your new visa application.

In general, however, it is always best to be truthful in all aspects of your visa application (I'm not saying you weren't before, despite what they thought). That means that if the application asks "Have you ever been deported from or refused entry into any country", you will probably have to answer "Yes" (depending on what actually happened, as per Kate Gregory's comment). You will probably also have to explain the circumstances that led to your prior refusal. They will make a decision based on what you state and your prior history which they will have in their records.

Answer (score -4):

Alternative: Get a tourist visa to the UK then go to Ireland.

The border between UK and Ireland is not often checked because the countries have a agreement (the [Common Travel Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area)) that if you get into one you are allowed into the other. When I traveled by ferry from Holyhead to Dublin last year the Irish immigration desks were completely unmanned. I understand that the land border is even less policed than that! (At the airport however the Irish do check UK arrivals for passports).

So your easiest way may be to travel to England, then take ferry to Northern Ireland (part of the UK) for which no passport control is required. Then go by bus to Irish Republic.

When you apply for the UK tourist visa I don't think you will have a question about being refused entry to Ireland, just about being refused to UK. Which I assume the answer is no. So long as your paperwork showing strong reasons to return to Georgia is in order and the purpose of your UK tourism is valid you should get in ok.

Comment: I would not recommend doing this. Since the OP has been refused entry to Ireland once, he is almost certainly required to apply for an Irish visa, and would technically be an illegal immigrant if he enters without one.  See this question about basically the same situation in reverse: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23090/uk-tourist-visa-refused-3-times-need-to-get-there-for-flight-home/23107#23107

Comment: It is in fact illegal, but might be the only option for OP in case he gets rejected again. However getting caught this time might get him banned from the EU for 5 years so it's quite risky.

Comment: Thanks for the link on a similar situation. 

Yes he would be illegal immigrant using this way and if caught the consequences might be high. However the risk of being caught given the open border is in my opinion very low. It depends what he plans to do in Ireland and for how long. 

If he is a well behaved tourist for a few weeks and returns over the land border I think there is little risk of detection. If he plans to live for months in Ireland with a girlfriend or get illegal work there then the risk of being caught goes up a lot.

Comment: I make the crossing between Dublin and Holyhead a couple of times a year, on average. I *would not rely on immigration desks being unmanned*. They are sometimes unmanned, but they quite often do have staff.

Comment: If either country concludes that the person intended to circumvent immigration controls, that will be the end of it for ALL countries in the CTA.

Comment: @JonathanReez Entering Ireland illegally is in no sense "the only option". The asker has the option of not entering Ireland at all.